# Django: Handling empty querysets in generic view

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am having a generic view which sometimes returns nothing.

How can I effectively handle it and raise a 404 in that case?

My approach is successfull, but hits the database.

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'template/quest.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        query = (
            MyModel.objects
            .filter(...)
            .filter(...)
        )

        if query.exists():
            return query
        else:
            raise Http404
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`allow_empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.allow_empty) to `False`:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    allow_empty = False
    template_name = 'template/quest.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

This will raise a `Http404` if the result of `get_queryset()` is empty (has length 0).